# JQuery image not centered in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have this page which works in Chrome & Firefox but not quite in IE. The page has pictures which, when clicked, shows a larger image centered on the page and the background is grayed out.

http://www.burrardtoastmasters.com/Gallery/2012-Summer.asp

Initially, I thought only IE 8 had the issue but I tested IE9 and the issue was there also. If you re-open the image, then the image may be centered. Another issue in IE is the background is not grayed out completely. There is some white space in the right vertical part of the browser. If you resize the browser to make it horizontally longer, the gray section is not dynamically resized.

This is the abbreviated html:

```
<div align="center">
<div id="thumbnail">

<A HREF="/Images/Gallery/2012/Summer_Banquet/01.jpg"><img id="800_600" src="/Images/Gallery/2012/Summer_Banquet/01-s.jpg" /></a>
<A HREF="/Images/Gallery/2012/Summer_Banquet/02.jpg"><img id="800_600" src="/Images/Gallery/2012/Summer_Banquet/02-s.jpg" /></a>    
<A HREF="/Images/Gallery/2012/Summer_Banquet/03.jpg"><img id="800_600" src="/Images/Gallery/2012/Summer_Banquet/03-s.jpg" /></a>       
<A HREF="/Images/Gallery/2012/Summer_Banquet/04.jpg"><img id="800_600" src="/Images/Gallery/2012/Summer_Banquet/04-s.jpg" /></a>       
<A HREF="/Images/Gallery/2012/Summer_Banquet/05.jpg"><img id="800_600" src="/Images/Gallery/2012/Summer_Banquet/05-s.jpg" /></a>

</div>              

<div id="largeimage"></div>
<div id="background"></div>

</div>
```

**Jquery section:**

```
// center the large image
jQuery.fn.center = function () {

    //document.write("win height: " +  ($(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop();

    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    // if thumbnail image is clicked, show large image
    $("#thumbnail img").click(function(e){

        // extract the large image's width & height from the image's id attribute
        var strId = this.id;
        var strWidth = strId.substring(0, strId.indexOf("_"));
        var strHeight = strId.substr(strId.indexOf("_") + 1, strId.length - strId.indexOf("_") - 1);

        // set the image's css size attributes
        $("#largeimage").css({"min-width" : strWidth + "px"});
        $("#largeimage").css({"min-height" : strHeight + "px"});

        $("#background").css({"opacity" : "0.7"})
                        .fadeIn("slow");

        $("#largeimage").html("<img src='"+$(this).parent().attr("href")+"' /><br/>")
                   .center()
                   .fadeIn("slow");

        return false;
    });

    // 27 - Escape key
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 27){
            $("#background").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#largeimage").fadeOut("slow");
        }
        });

    // if background is clicked, hide large image
    $("#background").click(function(){
        $("#background").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#largeimage").fadeOut("slow");
    });

    // if large image is clicked, hide it
    $("#largeimage").click(function(){
        $("#background").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#largeimage").fadeOut("slow");
    });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
img {
    border: none;
}
#thumbnail img {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#largeimage {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
    /*min-height: 600px;*/
    /*min-width: 800px; */
    color: #336699;
}
#background{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 220%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000000;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: probably not related to the problem, but you should keep your HTML tags the same case -- you've got upper case `<A>` and lower case `</a>`. Best practice to make them all lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Page has no doctype and therefore will not validate and is running in quirks mode. jQuery doesn't support quirks mode, and IE will often show css issues. Until you validate page , should run it through [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.burrardtoastmasters.com%2FGallery%2F2012-Summer.asp) , there isn't much point trying to troubleshoot css or script

You should be able to simply add an html5 docctype to fix short term validation. then check for broken tags again in W3C. For example of html5 doctype, look at source of this page

Answer (score 0):

In IE it looks like the image height and width until image is loaded completely,

so wait untill the image is loaded before centering it.

Or force a center() inside the load event of the images.

A simple suggession,

```
 var img = $("<img/><br/>");
img.appendTo("#largeimage").load(function(){
   $(this).parent().center();//for ie center agin after image is loaded
   }).attr( 'src' , $(this).parent().attr("href") );
//for non ie center immedietly
$("#largeimage").center().fadeIn("slow");
```

Rogh code, just take the idea

Comment: Ohh! first add the DOC type as @charlietfl suggested